# Rails 5 backend on subdomain does not save cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, subdomain

We are building a new application with Ruby on Rails. Our frontend is in a separate project and we do not make use of Rails' views. Our backend is located on `api.app.example.com`, whereas the frontend part is located on `app.example.com`. They are on different infrastructures (one is in AWS ECS, other is in S3). We are having trouble getting the session cookies to save in the browser.

I have done some research and found the `domain: :all` and `tld_length: 4` parameters, however these have been mostly been about same length subdomain, just different names. I have been trying some of the different combinations, but none of them has helped so far:

`domain: :all, tld_length: 3
domain: :all, tld_length: 4
domain: '.app.example.com', tld_length: 4
domain: '.example.com'
domain: :all`

The Set-Cookie header is received successfully by the browser, however it is not saved, therefor rendering any requests after login Unauthorized.

Is there something that I am forgetting? Can this be solved or should I just move the whole thing to single IP and use `/api` instead of `api.`?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @monteirobrena IIRC, it ended up being a CORS issue. `.app.example.com` (without tld_length) was the working option.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, if you are using Rails as an API project session storage is disabled by default. You should do something like this in one of your initializers:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_namespace'
```

I don't think subdomain should matter in this case, but I may be wrong.

Comment: I have this already set. The Set-Cookie header is sent with this, but it is not saved, I assume due to domain configuration.